# What happened to Paul in Friday the 13th, Part 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, friday-the-13th, friday-the-13th-part-2

At the end of *Friday the 13th Part 2*, Paul and Ginny are relieved that the sound at the door was merely a dog, and then Jason suddenly smashes through the window and grabs Ginny.  The next scene shows Ginny the next morning being placed onto a stretcher.  She calls out for Paul, who is nowhere to be seen.  It was never explained in the movie or any of the subsequential Friday the 13th movies what happened to him.

What happened to Paul?

Answer (score 1):

[From the **Friday the 13th Wiki**](http://fridaythe13th.wikia.com/wiki/Paul_Holt#Alternate_Ending):

> Paul's fate was more explained in an interview with Peter Bracke,
>   author of *Crystal Lake Memories: The Complete History of Friday the
>   13th*, in the *Friday the 13th Part II* DVD features. There he reveals
>   that **there was an unused ending in the movie. After Ginny questions
>   where Paul is, the scene switches to Mrs. Voorhees' head, which opens
>   its eyes and smiles, indicating that Jason had killed Paul**. But when
>   they filmed it, they thought it looked too silly. So it was taken out
>   of the movie.

From the same source, going by the available information in this movie and its sequel:

> Rumors say that Paul survived and is probably safe at home, laying
>   low. Though no proof is given, to support the rumors. Since Ginny had
>   blacked out during the last attempt, Paul may have fought off Jason to
>   prevent him from killing Ginny. Depending on who had the upper hand
>   Paul could have fought off Jason enough to run away afterwards, or was
>   killed defending Ginny and his body was taken by Jason, but **at the
>   beginning of *Part III*, a news broadcast reports the body count at
>   eight, thus excluding Paul from this count, possibly meaning that Paul
>   survived the ordeal.** However, the news man reporting 8 corpses were a
>   goof as only 6 corpses were found while the other 2 were at a shack
>   along with the corpse of Alice Hardy and the head of Pamela Voorhees,
>   however **Paul's body was not seen in the shack at the end of the movie**.